# Making a scrollbar work inside of a canvas populated with text that exceeds the dimensions of the canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

So, I've got a little program I'm writing. I'll do my best to only include the relevant bits of code. The concept is that there are three frames within a parent frame. The left side has a listbox with a scrollbar that I have working exactly as intended. The middle frame has a canvas that is populated with text/information that is dictated by clicking an item in the listbox on the left, and also displays a photo on the right. The thing is, the info in the middle typically far exceeds the size of the center frame, so I need a scrollbar. I have tried simply modifying my functioning scrollbar from the listbox, to no avail, and also other people's examples from this website and others, still to no avail. Any insight as to why my canvas scrollbar does not work would be greatly appreciated.

The code I have provided will not run, but including all of the relevant code to make it run would make the code really long and I am under the impression that we don't like super long bits of code to sift through here, and that anyone with even moderate knowledge of tkinter should see a glaring issue here without trying to run the code. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am still new to using SO and I want to do things the right way, while also not frustrating potential [temporary] mentors.

[image: What the program looks like- take note of the dead scrollbar in the center]

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.configure(bg="gray50")
root.geometry("1650x800")

# *** Function related to info_canvas scrollbar ***
def on_configure(event):  #commenting out "event" changes nothing...why?
    # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
    # when all widgets are in canvas
    info_canvas.configure(scrollregion=info_canvas.bbox('all'))  #doesn't seem to do anything...

# *** Create all Frames/Containers/Canvas ***
mainWindowFrame = Frame(root, bg="gray63", width=1200, height=650)
mainWindowLeftFrame = Frame(mainWindowFrame, bg="gray63", width=400, height=650, padx=10)
mainWindowCenterFrame = Frame(mainWindowFrame, bg="gray63", width=700, height=650)
mainWindowRightFrame = Frame(mainWindowFrame, bg="gray63", width=400, height=650)
info_canvas = Canvas(mainWindowCenterFrame, bg="gray63", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)

# *** Place Canvas ***
info_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
info_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=mainWindowCenterFrame, anchor='nw')  #commenting this out changes nothing

# *** Layout parameters of the main containers ***
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

mainWindowLeftFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainWindowLeftFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

mainWindowCenterFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainWindowCenterFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

mainWindowRightFrame.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainWindowRightFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


# *** Create & Place Scrollbars ***  <---this one works
rocket_scrollbar = Scrollbar(mainWindowLeftFrame, orient=VERTICAL)
lb.configure(yscrollcommand=rocket_scrollbar.set)
lb.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N+E+S+W)
lb.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
rocket_scrollbar.configure(command=lb.yview)
rocket_scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=40, sticky=N+S+W)

info_scrollbar = Scrollbar(mainWindowCenterFrame, command=info_canvas.yview, orient=VERTICAL)  # <-- this one doesn't
info_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=60, sticky=N+S)  
info_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = info_scrollbar.set)
info_canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# *** Bind List Box ***
lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', onselect)

# *** Bind Canvas ***
info_canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure) #commenting this out changes nothing...do I need it?

# *** Create all buttons/Labels ***  The labels below are what populate the canvas with text
rocketName = Label(info_canvas, font="-weight bold", bg="gray63", fg="white", pady=0)
rocketName.config(font=("Arial", 20))

infoLabel = Label(info_canvas, bg="gray63", fg="white")
infoLabel.config(font=("Arial", 11))

# *** Placement & Layout of all Buttons ***
rocketName.grid(row=0, column=0)
infoLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=25)
imgLabel = Label(mainWindowRightFrame, bg="gray63", border=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: there are plenty of Q on site about scrollbars, have u tried them and still not working ?

Comment: `info_canvas` is a child of `mainWindowCenterFrame` but you put the frame inside canvas: `info_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=mainWindowCenterFrame, anchor='nw')`.  What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, that's a fair point. Other tkinter-canvas-scrollbar questions on this site is where I got the code to make my listbox scrollbar work and also where I got the code for creating the canvas and attempting to make a scrollbar work in it. It's my attempt at integrating those question's answers into my code that I am failing and not understanding why.

Comment: @acw1668 My goal is to have the text provided by rocketName and infoLabel (which are inside info_canvas, which is itself inside mainWindowCenterFrame) to be scrollable. Are you saying that I've put info_canvas inside mainWindowCenterFrame and then turned around and put mainWindowCenterFrame inside info_canvas and that is the root of the issue? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: It may be the problem.  Normally another new frame is created and put into canvas using `create_window()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I see! I'll try to rearrange things based on your advice. Thank you!

Comment: @acw1668 So, just to confirm: I created a frame and put a canvas in it. And in order to make the text labels inside the canvas scrollable, I need to actually put them inside of another frame that is inside the canvas? And that's what create_window is doing? If that is the case, when I do create_window((0,0), window= (am I naming a new frame here or assigning the location of an unnamed frame?) I apologize for not understanding. I've been looking at several pages about create_window but they seem to be assuming you understand other things and are not very explicit.

Comment: Yes, you need to create another frame as a child of the canvas, then put it into the canvas using `create_window()`.  The text labels should be then children of the frame.  So `mainWindowCenterFrame` contains the canvas (`info_canvas`) and the scrollbar (`info_scrollbar)`, `info_canvas` contains the new frame and the new frame contains the labels to be scrolled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219168/discussion-between-seralyn-campbell-and-acw1668).

Comment: If all you're displaying is text, you don't need an inner frame. You can draw text directly on a canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley Hey Bryan, thanks for your input! So, I actually was drawing the text directly onto the canvas at first, but my scrollbar didn't work until I put it inside of a new frame created by create_window. Any idea why that might have been the case? I did get this scrollbar working in the end, but it doesn't respond to mouse input and requires me to physically slide the scrollbar. It also smears the text when I scroll quickly, unlike my listbox + scrollbar combo. And for some reason changes the positiion of where the text starts differently on differrent entries.